# How do I specify plugins as an array in options browserify?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify

I would like to be able to configure my browserify plugins under opts.plugin.

I imagine it would look something like this...

```
let plugins = [pluginOne(opt),pluginTwo(opt),...];
let options = {
    entries: [],
    plugin: plugins,
};

let bundler = browserify(config);
```

As opposed to...

```
.plugin(pluginOne, {
    o: ['path1/file2.js', 'path2/file2.js']
})
```

My reasoning for wanting to do this is code readability.